# Layer control using leaftejs and vuejs

Tags: leaflet, vue-component, sidebar, vue-cli

Everyone I am a junior developer at NESAC(ISRO).
I am working on a project with vue JS and leaflet JS. So my task is:-

1. Using Leaflet JS, I have to render a map on the screen.
2. Set markers at  "n" specific locations on the renderd map.
3. Create a sidebar with a checkbox of various entities such as cities, restaurants, parks etc.
4. Develop a Vue app such that, I create my different components on the components folder, so that all my components go through App.vue file and gets renderd at the index.html, i.e. my browser.
5. And, now I have to make a Layer control function such that each of my entities gets different reactions. Eg. If I click the restaurant checkbox at the sidebar, then all my restaurant leaflet markers should be shown on the screen, but each entity should have different reactivity.

[Github Link.](https://github.com/RUP25/Vue-LeafletJS.git)

Comment: Nobody will give you a solution. Please read [how-to-ask first](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am sorry for my way of asking the question. I am new to stack overflow. And this is my first question. Can you please help me with this problem.  @GrzegorzT.

Comment: Here we ask specific questions about a problem. We do not write out a list of questions asking for a solution :)
For example, I already have some code and something doesn't work. You show the code, preferably some working example, and the community helps you.
As in life at work, you don't work on everything at once, but only on one thing;)
Break down this list of questions into several separate threads. You are working on a map that does not show up, you create a thread with this question and code, etc. @RUP25

Comment: I don't know much about vue, but I made a set of simple examples of how to use a leaflet in pure js [leaflet-examples](https://tomik23.github.io/leaflet-examples/#controlling-different-groups-of-markers) Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm package for that - [Vue2Leaflet](https://github.com/vue-leaflet/Vue2Leaflet)

Here is docu: https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app

And simple Map with Vue.js and leaflet:

```
<template>

  <div style="height: 350px;">
    <div class="info" style="height: 15%">
      <span>Center: {{ center }}</span>
      <span>Zoom: {{ zoom }}</span>
      <span>Bounds: {{ bounds }}</span>
    </div>
    <l-map
      style="height: 80%; width: 100%"
      :zoom="zoom"
      :center="center"
      @update:zoom="zoomUpdated"
      @update:center="centerUpdated"
      @update:bounds="boundsUpdated"
    >
      <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
    </l-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {LMap, LTileLayer} from 'vue2-leaflet';

export default {
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
  },
  data () {
    return {
      url: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      zoom: 3,
      center: [47.413220, -1.219482],
      bounds: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    zoomUpdated (zoom) {
      this.zoom = zoom;
    },
    centerUpdated (center) {
      this.center = center;
    },
    boundsUpdated (bounds) {
      this.bounds = bounds;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It's just a wrapper for a leaflet and you have complete access to all the leaflet functions through:

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.map = this.$refs.map.mapObject;
    });
}
```

I think that can be a good start for you.